# Выделение элемента изображения при наведении

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите, как лучше и быстрее реализовать такую идею. Есть изображение - на ней изображена строительная техника. Нужно, чтобы при наведении на камаз, например, он подсвечивался и вылезала подсказка. Вроде нужно area использовать, а можно как-то поскорее это реализовать, а то сложно карту изображения создавать, объекты не простые.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/yv43qa5c/

http://jsfiddle.net/g8Lpuroj/

Comment: Координаты Вы прописали, спасибо, а как добавить при наведении, например, свечение машины и подсказку?

Comment: как вариант http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/43217/
http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/

Comment: Да, это как раз то, что нужно. Но привязать я не знаю как, подскажете?

Comment: Да, все, разобрался. Спасибо огромное.